# Cypress - Vue Js Button click event is not working

Tags: cypress

I have Vue Js application in which there is a detail page which has multiple tabs in it.
When i am click on 2nd tab button click event not fires.
Can anyone please suggest the workaround? So that i can proceed.

By default selection on 1st tab and data loads immediately but when click on 2nd tab loader loading only but there is no response.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add HTML code and cypress code that you tried?

Comment: Here is the cypress code for reference.

describe('Order Data', () => {
    let btnText='APPROVED';
    it('Test Google page', function () {
        cy.pause();
        cy.get('a.nav-link.master-data').click();
        cy.pause();
       assertHeadingIsPresent('button.s-btn.s-btn--secondary.approve-btn.s-btn--submit',btnText)
    
    })
});

Comment: Html Code:
<a role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2" target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link master-data" id="__BVID__14___BV_tab_button__" tabindex="-1">
        Reconciliation: Master Data
        <i class="material-icons idt-match-icon">check_circle</i></a>